# Is it possible to allocate memory to a query in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have query inside a stored procedure and i am trying to see is there a way to specify memory that required for this query to use.

i know on server level we can change Minimum memory to use Query but i that is for all queries on the server but i am looking for an option at specific query level.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but if you share why you want to do this we may be able to give you options. The specific version and edition of Sql Server that you're using may help, as well.

Comment: procedure sort component  is spilling into Tempdb in production but not in Development, both are same execution plan, Development configuration is 8GB RAM & 1 Core and PROD is 40GB &8core, so the question is query in PROD spilling(Hash Match & Sort component ) into tempdb when there is enough memory.

Comment: If Sql Server is using tempdb for this, rather than memory, it's because it needs that memory elsewhere due to load or the size of the production data vs development data. If it needs more memory, put more memory into the server, or tune the query to use less (if possible).

Comment: production has 50GB RAM and drives are SSD drives, looks like sql engine is not able to allocate proper memory or I am missing some memory related settings, I found where we can increase minimum memory for query but that is for all queries on server.

Comment: Are you certain it is this query doing this? Are you certain that using the Tempdb is causing a large performance issue? You could post the query, and we can see if there is anything that can be done to make it more effcient.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method or option provided to user in SQL Server to reserve memory to particular query. The reservation is done internally by database engine before query is executed. If you are thinking about [Resource governor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933944(v=sql.105).aspx) I dont know much about it but you can try

When query is executed it is compiled and then optimizer executes the query. If query is totally new it might need *some* amount of memory to create multiple plans and then select best plan from that. This is called cost based optimization. A lack of memory can delay the this process. Next comes query execution and assuming you are doing sorts and Hash joins in your query it would require memory perhaps sometimes significant amount of memory depending on rows it has to sort.

When such query executes it calculates two memory parameters `required memory` and `additional memory` required memory is minimum memory required to run sort operations and additional memory is memory required to store additional sorts when complete query would execute. This is called as query memory grants. Now in your case I assume stats are either outdated or there is a memory pressure or memory currently is not free. When your query ran it asked for some amount of memory, SQL Server is not going to grant all memory but would grant only minimum memory so that query executon can start and would reserve some memory for query based on sorting it is going to do. But when your query ran either due to skewed stats or due to memory pressure additional memory for storing sorted data could not be obtained and this led to spilling.

You can try to update stats and see if query prepares a better plan and would avoid spliing or increase the value of max server memory so as to provide more memory to buffer pool. There can also be chance that you need to change join order in query or may be rewrite a query.

Complete description of how memory is allocated when query runs is in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlqueryprocessing/archive/2010/02/16/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant.aspx)

Comment: Final link to how memory is allocated is dead, but I think this might be the same article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/ba-p/383595. Note it is not explicitly stated whether it's applicable to modern SQL Server versions as of 2024.

MSFT docs have a newer article on memory grants: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-memory-grant-issues (this also links to the above blog post!).

Answer (score 1):

There are a pair of query hints, `MIN_GRANT_PERCENT` and `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT`, which can be used to set bounds for an individual query. The bounds are as a percentage of the configured server memory rather than in absolute bytes.

I'm not sure that this is precisely what you were asking for, but it may be close enough to be useful.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver16#max_grant_percent--numeric_value